# Add Spring Boot Profile to Sleuth/Zipkin logs

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm using these dependencies:

```
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin'
```

Is there a possibility to add the current active profile(s) to each log line? This would make it possible to filter logs based on the profiles in Splunk/ELK/...

So instead of

```
2017-03-13 13:38:30.465  INFO [app,,,] 19220 --- [           main] com.company.app.Application    : Started Application in 20.682 seconds (JVM running for 22.166)
```

it should log

```
2017-03-13 13:38:30.465  INFO [app,,,] [dev] 19220 --- [           main] com.company.app.Application    : Started Application in 20.682 seconds (JVM running for 22.166)
```

**EDIT:**
Based on Marcin's answer, I implemented it as follows:

application.yml

```
logging:
  pattern:
    level: "%X{profiles} %5p"
```

ProfileLogger.java

```
public class ProfileLogger implements SpanLogger {

    private final Environment environment;
    private final Logger log;
    private final Pattern nameSkipPattern;

    @Autowired
    public ProfileLogger(String nameSkipPattern, final Environment environment) {
        this.nameSkipPattern = Pattern.compile(nameSkipPattern);
        this.environment = environment;
        this.log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    }

    private void setProfiles() {
        MDC.put("profiles", Arrays.toString(environment.getActiveProfiles()));
    }

    @Override
    public void logStartedSpan(Span parent, Span span) {
        setProfiles();
        ...
    }
    ... // (as https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/log/Slf4jSpanLogger.java)
}
```

LogConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class LogConfig {

    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public LogConfig(final Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    SpanLogger getLogger() {
        return new ProfileLogger("", environment);
    }
}
```

This prints logs like the following:

```
2017-03-13 14:47:02.796   INFO 22481 --- [           main] com.company.app.Application    : Started Application in 16.115 seconds (JVM running for 16.792)
2017-03-13 14:47:32.684 [localhost, swagger] TRACE 22481 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.c.app.config.ProfileLogger    : Starting span: [Trace: bfcdd2ce866efbff, Span: bfcdd2ce866efbff, Parent: null, exportable:true]
```

This is already good but not completely what I'm looking for yet.
I'd like to add the profile from the beginning -> even the "Started Application" should contain the profile - if possible. Secondly, I'd like to move the `profiles` between `INFO` and `22481`.

One more question came up during implementation: In the linked implementation there is this statement:

```
if (this.log.isTraceEnabled()) {
    this.log.trace(text, span);
}
```

does that mean you only send traces if log-level is set to TRACE? If so, how could I improve logging to stdout with that approach (given a log-level of debug/info/warn)? I think the log-pattern is overriden by Sleuth/Zipkin upon importing the dependencies and thus, local logging looks the same as tracing. Eventually I'm interested in having the profile displayed in local stdout as well as in Zipkin.

**EDIT 2:** With the help of Marcin, I have changed the pattern by introducing a `resources/logback-spring.xml` file containing these lines:

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="activeSpringProfiles" source="spring.profiles.active"/>
<!-- Example for logging into the build folder of your project -->
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${BUILD_FOLDER:-build}/${activeSpringProfiles:-}"/>​

<!-- You can override this to have a custom pattern -->
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) [${activeSpringProfiles:-}] %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>
```

Note that you have to add a `bootstrap.yml` file too in order to have the application name correctly displayed. Without a `bootstrap.yml` file, the above log-pattern just prints "bootstrap" as application name.

The `bootstrap.yml` just contains

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app
```

in my case. Everything else is configured in application-[profile].yml

Now everything works as desired:

```
2017-03-13 15:58:21.291  INFO [app,,,] [localhost,swagger] 27519 --- [           main] com.company.app.keyserver.Application    : Started Application in 17.565 seconds (JVM running for 18.232)
```

Comment: You're mixing all possible patterns from what I see :P Why suddenly are we talking about sending spans to zipkin in terms of logging? It has nothing to do with each other. If trace level is enabled then we are logging additional text like "Continued Span".

Comment: For now it's not possible to add Sleuth at that point in time cause actually it makes no sense. Tracing should be present in business operations. Not in any operation. To make the logging pattern available you'd have to add the configuration that you're doing to bootstrapping phase.

Comment: You'll need to completely change the logging pattern if you want to do things like this. Maybe it's better then to try the `logback-spring.xml` way like here - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps/blob/master/service1/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml#L5-L11 . I'm resolving the application name there so maybe you could do the same with active profiles and won't need to write any code? You can try to do this and ping back if it went well.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. Eventually I just wanna see the profiles in my local stdout so it gets logged to Splunk :-) In order to do that I thought I had to adjust logging parameters in Sleuth or Zipkin because one of the dependency changed the log-pattern (locally) when I initially imported it. You pointed out I have to implement my own SpanLogger in order to do that (right?). I was simply confused by the fact that your log()-method checks whether TRACE is enabled or not but I see now that this is only for your own logging.

Comment: Maybe let's move the discussion to Gitter? https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth Also please check my answers and try to apply this approach to logging. Should help.

Comment: I'll try your `logback-spring.xml` approach and will ping back again with the result. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your logback approach worked, thank you. I added my findings to the question, maybe you'd like to add an answer to get the credits :) 
cheers

Comment: I've updated the answer with the `logback-spring.xml` approach :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course - you have to just provide your own logging format (e.g. via  `logging.pattern.level` - check https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html for more info). Then you have to register your own `SpanLogger` bean implementation where you will take care of adding the value of a spring profile via MDC  (you can take a look at this as an example https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/log/Slf4jSpanLogger.java )

**UPDATE:**

There's another solution for more complex approach that seems much easier than rewriting Sleuth classes. You can try the `logback-spring.xml` way like here - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps/blob/master/service1/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml#L5-L11 . I'm resolving the application name there so maybe you could do the same with active profiles and won't need to write any code?

Comment: Thank you very much @marcin-grzejszczak. I tried to follow your instructions and updated my question with a draft you might assist in some details.